# Is there spa mode for Esbuild's serve?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, esbuild

I'm using esbuild to develop a SPA and there's a serve function that spins up a dev server, however, if I go to any routes eg "/about", this results in a 404 as because this is a SPA, there is no actual file at that route.

If I could resolve all requests to "/" then that'll fix this issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I just added `--single` flag to my [package](https://github.com/hyrious/esbuild-serve), which is a simple wrapper of `esbuild --serve`. You can check [my source code](https://github.com/hyrious/esbuild-serve/blob/8f97dac0fb034c1403271085d5b69645395e165c/src/index.ts#L83-L87) to see how it works.

If the proxy request returns 404, then try again with `req.path` set to `/`, that's it.